# Best way to wait to page ready selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have big web page that load a lot of content with JS on background.

I want to wait until the web page will be ready, What I'm  doing for now is:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("headless");

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
{
     driver.Url = "http://MYURL.com";

     bool IsPageReady = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(
                    d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState".Equals("complete");

     if (IsPageReady)
          queryResult = driver.PageSource;
      else
           Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

My question is if there is another methods to do that?

Comment: I recomend you to use tasks... Do you know how? Should I post an answer?

Comment: @AdrianEfford I would love if you can post answer about that

Comment: Selenium already waits for the page to be ready.  WebDriverWaits are used for DOM updates that happen without a page load.  When you navigate to a site, the page is always loaded.  (If the site performs DOM updates after a page load you would need the above code... or webdriverwaits for each DOM element you are going to work with.)  I don't think checking for readyState is all that reliable... different scripts could begin executing at different times... better to wait for each element you are going to work with.  Quicker, too.